# How to add file name and date dynamically in *.licenseheader file in VS2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed license header manager from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StefanWenig.LicenseHeaderManager.

I need to add file name and date on which the license header is getting added.

```
extensions: designer.cs generated.cs
extensions: .cs .cpp .h
/**
* Project Name
* File Name: Test.cs
* Description : Something about the file
* @2018(Year or Date) Company Name Inc. All rights reserved
**/
extensions: .aspx .ascx
<%-- 
/**
* Project Name
* File Name: Test.cs
* Description : Something about the file
* @2018(Year or Date) Company Name Inc. All rights reserved
**/
--%>
extensions: .vb
'Sample license text.
extensions:  .xml .config .xsd
<!--
/**
* Project Name
* File Name: Test.cs
* Description : Something about the file
* @2018(Year or Date) Company Name Inc. All rights reserved
**/
-->
```

Is it possible to add it dynamically or is there any better approach? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to define file name and created date time dynamically.
We can use **"%FileName%"**, **"%CreationYear%"** etc.

For example :

```
extensions: designer.cs generated.cs
extensions: .cs .cpp .h
/**
* Project Name
* File Name: %FileName%
* @%CreationYear%(To display Year) Company Name Inc. All rights reserved
**/
```

For more details,

https://github.com/rubicon-oss/LicenseHeaderManager/wiki/Expendable-Properties.